# Class composition in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, composition

I want to build a class that can compose multiple objects and use any of their interfaces.

Class A can use any of the interfaces of Class B and C

B can use any of the interfaces of C

C can use any of the interfaces of B

I have the above functionality written in JavaScript and I was wondering what's the best and correct way to achieve the same using TypeScript:

```js
import { findLast, isFunction } from "lodash";

class Composite {
  constructor(behavior) {
    this.behaviors = [];

    if (behavior) {
      this.add(behavior);
    }
  }

  add(behavior) {
    behavior.setClient(this);
    this.behaviors.push(behavior);
    return this;
  }

  getMethod(method) {
    const b = findLast(this.behaviors, (behavior) =>
      isFunction(behavior[method])
    );
    return b[method].bind(b);
  }
}

class Behavior1 {
  foo() {
    console.log("B1: foo");
  }

  foo2() {
    console.log("B1: foo2");
    this.getMethod("bar")();
  }

  setClient(client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  getMethod(method) {
    return this.client.getMethod(method);
  }
}

class Behavior2 {
  foo() {
    console.log("B2: foo");
    this.getMethod("foo2")();
  }

  bar() {
    console.log("B2: bar");
  }

  setClient(client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  getMethod(method) {
    return this.client.getMethod(method).bind(this);
  }
}

const c = new Composite();
c.add(new Behavior1());
c.add(new Behavior2());
c.getMethod("foo")();
c.getMethod("bar")();

// Output:
// B2: foo
// B1: foo2
// B2: bar
// B2: bar
```

Link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-poitras-56f4e?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Just asking. Both behaviors duplicate the `setClient` and `getMethod`, shouldn't it be a part of a shared interface? Also, the composite's `getClient` returns a last behavior that contains given method but what if there's no matching behavior? Looks like this is not covered here and null reference exception can occur. Also, last questions, what's the bigger picture behind this?

Comment: 1) Yeah, `setClient` and `getMethod` should be part of another class and each behavior must extend that class.

2) If there's no matching behavior an error must be thrown. I haven't added these checks to keep the example as simple as possible.

3) The bigger picture is that I'm building a SDK and I want to keep everything separated and modular, but to still allow the client to use a single class to invoke everything that's supported.

Comment: Is there any benefit from this single facade hiding everything behing but in the same time making all invocations dynamic (= slower)? I admit I can't find a clear example of a similar approach.

Comment: Well, it allows you to build different features (by implementing a new Behavior class) without even touching the base class or any of the other Behavior classes. You simply can add the new feature and use it. You can also override interfaces easily.

Comment: I suggest you think of your `Composite` like just nothing more than a factory. Instead of *registering an instance* you could **register a function that creates the instance** (this allows finer life-time control). Instead of *asking for a method* you could let clients **ask for an object of specific key** (Javascript) or **specific type/interface** (TypeScript). But, hey, this sounds like is a factory on steroids, exactly what a DI container is. Why don't you then try to find an existing JS/TS container, like the [Inversify](https://inversify.io/) and use it instead of writing your own one?

Comment: Not sure if Inversify isn't going to be an overkill, but I will take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: It's just an example you don't have to use directly. But the general idea of DI should help your approach get closer to common way of doing it. Plus, example TS implementations will let you resolve your primary issue which is moving your code to strictly typed environment.

Comment: Is it imperative that a behavior adds multiple methods?  Doing it that way makes it harder to define the signature for the functions -- that each one takes no arguments.  With something like the Command pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern every behavior would have one zero-argument method `execute()`.  If we define a behavior as a key-value object where all values are functions with 0 args, I'm concerned that will interfere if it the class wants to have internal methods that aren't part of its behaviors.  Anyways I'll take a stab - I love designing!

Comment: As far as typing the current setup, the issue that I'm running into a bunch is that certain things might not be defined.  The Behavior might not have set its client.  The method for a name might not have been found.  So I don't know if you want to handle these situations but returning `undefined` or throwing an `Error`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot that's not ideal about your setup.  I might post a separate answer with an alternate setup, but for now I just want to show you how to convert your code to typescript.

Keep in mind that typescript errors exist to help you prevent runtime errors, and there are some genuine potential runtime errors that we need to avoid.  If a `Behavior` calls `getMethod` before calling `setClient` to set `this.client` that will be a fatal error.  If you try to call the returned method from `getMethod` on a `Composite` or a `Behavior` where the name didn't match a method that's another fatal error. And so on.

You choose to handle certain situations by throwing an `Error` with the expectation that it will be caught later on.  Here I am preferring to "fail gracefully" and just do nothing or return `undefined` if we can't do what we want.  The [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` helps.

When defining an interface for a function argument, it's best to keep it to the minimum necessities and not require any extraneous properties.

The only thing that a `Behavior` requires of its `Client` is a `getMethod` method.

```
interface CanGetMethod {
  getMethod(name: string): MaybeMethod;
}
```

We use the union of `undefined` and a void function in a few places, so I am saving it to an alias name for convenience.

```
type MaybeMethod = (() => void) | undefined;
```

The `Composite` calls `setClient` on its behaviors, so they must implement this interface.

```
interface CanSetClient {
  setClient(client: CanGetMethod): void;
}
```

It also expects that its methods take zero arguments, but we can't really declare this with the current setup.  It is possible to add a string index to a class, but that would conflict with our `getMethod` and `setClient` arguments which do require arguments.

One of the typescript errors that you get a bunch is *`Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined',* so I created a helper method to wrap a function call.

```
const maybeCall = (method: MaybeMethod): void => {
  if (method) {
    method();
  }
};
```

In typescript, classes need to declare the types for their properties.  `Composite` gets an array of behaviors `behaviors: CanSetClient[];` while the behaviors get a client `client?: CanGetMethod;`.  Note that the client **must** be typed as optional because it is not present when calling `new()`.

After that, it's mostly just a matter of annotating argument and return types.

I have declared the interfaces that each class implements, ie. `class Behavior1 implements CanGetMethod, CanSetClient`, but this is not required.  Any object fits the interface `CanGetMethod` if it has a `getMethod` property with the right types, whether it explicitly declares `CanGetMethod` in its type or not.

```
class Composite implements CanGetMethod {
  behaviors: CanSetClient[];

  constructor(behavior?: CanSetClient) {
    this.behaviors = [];

    if (behavior) {
      this.add(behavior);
    }
  }

  add(behavior: CanSetClient): this {
    behavior.setClient(this);
    this.behaviors.push(behavior);
    return this;
  }

  getMethod(method: string): MaybeMethod {
    const b = findLast(this.behaviors, (behavior) =>
      isFunction(behavior[method])
    );
    return b ? b[method].bind(b) : undefined;
  }
}

class Behavior1 implements CanGetMethod, CanSetClient {
  client?: CanGetMethod;

  foo() {
    console.log("B1: foo");
  }

  foo2() {
    console.log("B1: foo2");
    maybeCall(this.getMethod("bar"));
  }

  setClient(client: CanGetMethod): void {
    this.client = client;
  }

  getMethod(method: string): MaybeMethod {
    return this.client?.getMethod(method);
  }
}

class Behavior2 implements CanGetMethod, CanSetClient {
  client?: CanGetMethod;

  foo() {
    console.log("B2: foo");
    maybeCall(this.getMethod("foo2"));
  }

  bar() {
    console.log("B2: bar");
  }

  setClient(client: CanGetMethod) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  getMethod(method: string): MaybeMethod {
    return this.client?.getMethod(method)?.bind(this);
  }
}

const c = new Composite();
c.add(new Behavior1());
c.add(new Behavior2());
maybeCall(c.getMethod("foo"));
maybeCall(c.getMethod("bar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can review my other answer to see some of the issues and concerns with the previous approach.  Here I've created a completely different version from the ground up.  There is less code repetition and less tight coupling between the classes.

Behaviors no longer call methods directly and no longer store a reference to the client.  Instead, they receive the client (or any object which call get and call methods) as an argument of their `register` method.

We define any object which can lookup and call methods as a `MethodAccessor`

```
interface MethodAccessor {
  getMethod(name: string): () => void;
  safeCallMethod(name: string): boolean;
}
```

We define any object that provides behaviors through a `register` method as a `BehaviorWrapper`.  These objects can call functions from other objects by calling `getMethod` or `safeCallMethod` on the `helper` argument.

```
type KeyedBehaviors = Record<string, () => void>;

interface BehaviorWrapper {
  register(helper: MethodAccessor): KeyedBehaviors;
}
```

A behavior which does not need instance variables could be a pure function rather than a class.

```
const functionBehavior = {
  register(composite: MethodAccessor) {
    return {
      foo: () => console.log("B1: foo"),
      foo2: () => {
        console.log("B1: foo2");
        composite.safeCallMethod("bar");
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Class behaviors can make use of instance variables in their methods.

```
class ClassBehavior {
  name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  bar = () => {
    console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}`);
  };

  register() {
    return {
      bar: this.bar
    };
  }
}
```

There is some redundancy here when defining a method like `bar` separately rather than inline as an arrow function within the `return` object.  The reason that I am having the methods come from `register` rather than using all class methods is so that I can have stricter typing on them.  You could have methods in your class which *do* require args and as long as they aren't part of the `register` returned object then it's not a problem.

Our class `Composite` now stores its behaviors in a keyed object rather than an array.  Newly added behaviors of the same name will overwrite older ones.  Our `getMethod` is typed such that it always returns a method, and will throw an `Error` if none was found.  I've added a new method `safeCallMethod` to call a method by name.  If a method was found, it calls it and returns `true`.  If no method was found, it catches the error and returns `false`.

```
class Composite implements MethodAccessor {
  behaviors: KeyedBehaviors = {};

  constructor(behavior?: BehaviorWrapper) {
    if (behavior) {
      this.add(behavior);
    }
  }

  // add all behaviors from a behavior class instance
  add(behavior: BehaviorWrapper): this {
    this.behaviors = {
      ...this.behaviors,
      ...behavior.register(this)
    };
    return this;
  }

  // lookup a method by name and return it
  // throws error on not found
  getMethod(method: string): () => void {
    const b = this.behaviors[method];
    if (!b) {
      throw new Error(`behavior ${method} not found`);
    }
    return b;
  }

  // calls a method by name, if it exists
  // returns true if called or false if not found
  safeCallMethod(method: string): boolean {
    try {
      this.getMethod(method)();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```